# not able to find iframe in protractor tests

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to find an element which is within iframe. So i try to switch to iframe.

The iframe in html:

```
<iframe id="id_of_iframe"  data-app-id="com.s-h.ph.pr" class="external-app ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-if="!vm.appDisabled"  ng-attr-sandbox="{{vm.iframeConfig.sandbox ? vm.iframeConfig.sandbox : ''}}" tp-onload="vm.sendCurrentRouteToIFrame()" style="border: none; border-width: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals"></iframe>
```

code used:

```
 browser.switchTo().frame('id_of_iframe');
```

I get the following error:

```
 Failed: no such frame
      (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c58
10906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
  Stack:
    NoSuchFrameError: no such frame
      (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c58
10906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
        at WebDriverError (C:\Users\z002ex9t\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pr
otractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
        at NoSuchFrameError (C:\Users\z002ex9t\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:180:5)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\z002ex9t\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:505:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\z002ex9t\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\z002ex9t\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

I am using the following versions :
"protractor": "5.1.2",
"jasmine": "2.8.0"
 webdriver-manager 12.0.6

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why are you providing it as a snippet containing only that line, is that supposed to be testable?

Comment: Please share the HTML and URL

Comment: Failed: no such frame issue said this is there is really a frame

Comment: yes, the iframe is present in html

Comment: URL Please so we can check

Comment: If you're using Chrome, tell me which version, please?

Comment: Try with xpath //iframe[@data-app-id='com.s-h.ph.pr']

Comment: @user2439903 u got the solution

Comment: @user10089632 Chrome version is Version 61.0.3163.100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with  passing index by giving

```
browser.switchTo().frame("index of the frame");
```

This is the most simple one and may be we can figure out whether it was an issue with id or something else. Because the id you have given is straight forward and I don't see a reason why it should fail

Comment: It is not necessary that it have only one frame

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: @aayya he tried the same solution. Strange why it is nt work

Comment: I guess he tried with ID and and I am asking to try with index

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver's `driver.switchTo().frame()` method takes one of the three possible arguments:

1. Number (Index of the iframe)
2. Name or ID (if iframe has ID or Name attribute)
3. WebElement (if iframe needs to be identified by any custom logic)

**Example:**

Consider below iframes are available in your DOM.

**Iframe1:**

```
<iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe_1" class="iframe_1">
</iframe>
```

**Iframe2:**

```
<iframe name="iframe2" id="iframe_2" class="iframe_2">
</iframe>
```

**Iframe3:**

```
<iframe name="iframe3" id="iframe_3" class="iframe_3">
</iframe>
```

**Using Index:**

- `browser.switchTo().frame(0)` - This will switch to `iframe1`
- `browser.switchTo().frame(1)` - This will switch to `iframe2`
- `browser.switchTo().frame(2)` - This will switch to `iframe3`

**Name or ID:**

- `browser.switchTo().frame("iframe1")` or `browser.switchTo().frame("iframe_1")` - This will switch to `iframe1`
- `browser.switchTo().frame("iframe2")` or `browser.switchTo().frame("iframe_2")` - This will switch to `iframe2`
- `browser.switchTo().frame("iframe3")` or `browser.switchTo().frame("iframe_3")` - This will switch to `iframe3`

**WebElement**

- `browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.tagName("iframe")).getWebElement())` or `browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.css(".iframe_1")).getWebElement())` - This will switch to `iframe1`
- `browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.css(".iframe_2")).getWebElement())` or `browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.xpath(".//iframe[@id='iframe_2']")).getWebElement())` - This will switch to `iframe2`

Answer (score 0):

If there is a frame use `xpath`

```
//iframe[@data-app-id='com.s-h.ph.pr']
```

But still I suggest you first have to used `id`